# Unwanted border at ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, android

I have been reading similar posts but none has solved my problem.

My Activity consists of this RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/initial_launch_text"
            style="@style/initialLaunchTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="Test" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/initial_launch_skip_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@color/initial_launch_skip_button_text"
            android:onClick="skipButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/activity_initial_launch_skip_button_skip" />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/initial_launch_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/initial_launch_text"
            android:layout_above="@+id/initial_launch_skip_button"
            android:src="@drawable/flower"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

All I want is a TextView on top, a Button at the bottom and **an ImageView with 1dp black border** in between. But what I get is an unwanted thick black border above and below the image:

[image]

How can I get rid of that??

Comment: this "border" is not a border between the views, it's just that the aspect ratio of the image is not the same as the imageview's.. try to change the scaleType of the imageView to centerCrop

Comment: remove adjustViewBounds attribite

Comment: @ercan i posted the layout that problem is with scaletype and You cannot see the border for PNG images its also a problem you just manage it.or you will set the  different color background for PNG Images only..All the best

Comment: @psking removing adjustViewBounds doesn't help.

Comment: @Bob I don't want to change the aspect ratio nor crop the image.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/initial_launch_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/initial_launch_text"
            android:layout_above="@+id/initial_launch_skip_button"
            android:src="@drawable/flower"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />
```

to this:

```
 <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/initial_launch_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/initial_launch_text"
            android:layout_above="@+id/initial_launch_skip_button"
            android:src="@drawable/flower"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#000000"
         android:layout_margin="1dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I designed this layout for you but it has one issue with this type of issues why am saying this means you are going with PNG file you may get two types of layout i will show the layouts you should use JPEG then only you can get this type of layouts....

[image: This one for JPEG Image]

[image: This one for PNG file Image]

Layout code.....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/initial_launch_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:text="Test" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/initial_launch_skip_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="skipButtonClicked"
    android:text="Skip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/initial_launch_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/initial_launch_skip_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/initial_launch_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't want to change the aspect ratio nor crop the image.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the `ImageView` with a `LinearLayout` using following parameters did the trick:

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/initial_launch_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/initial_launch_text"
            android:layout_above="@+id/initial_launch_skip_button"
            android:src="@drawable/flower"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```